# For which flutter widgets we need to use const?

Tags: flutter, dart

I understand the benefits of `const` and the widgets will not rebuilt on state change, but still it's so obvious when you see below code that they are constants and I was hoping flutter handled it automatically. Or, flutter is taking care of it already and I am unaware?

```
// This makes sense to me but with above mentioned concern 
const Text('Your Text Here')
const Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 20.0),
```

Anyhow, my question is: Is it fine to define `SizedBox` & `EdgeInsets` widgets as constants(const) as it defined below?

```
Padding(
  padding:
      const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, right: 6.0, bottom: 16.0, left: 16.0),
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
      const Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 20.0),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: Normally, in the occasions like assigning the sizes and etc, you'd better not use constant values and respect the responsiveness of the app, which is the change in  sizes according to the various mobile screens.instead of hard-coded values consider using MediaQuery and stuff.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically flutter trying to update some widgets in tree, and if it const, nothing to update. Here you can find explanation.
https://dev.to/pedromassango/flutter-performance-tips-1-const-constructors-4j41

You need to know one an important thing, that if you changed widget in a tree, everything after this widget will be removed and redrawed(not updated). So, if you define it as const, nothing will be removed. And that is OK(answer on you question)
Also I recommend to read how flutter rebuild screen and update widgets:
https://www.didierboelens.com/2019/09/flutter-internals/

And the last great article about performance
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html#performance-considerations

Answer (score 2):

In the case of state change(i.e `setState`), `const widget` does not rebuild again.

Although you should avoid redundant `const`.

> For more, read [DON’T use const redundantly](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#dont-use-const-redundantly)