# Why is Flutter telling me to add 'const' to a stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter is highlighting my `Login()` below with a yellow line telling me that the `const` keyword should be used to improve performance. But my `Login` widget is a stateful widget, whose state can change. What is is about my `Login` widget that makes it appropriate to add the `const` keyword here?

**wrapper.dart:**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      return Login(); //Warning points here, telling me to change the line to 'return const Login();'
    });
  }
}
```

**login.dart:**

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use const sometimes when instantiating a widget in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69179058/why-use-const-sometimes-when-instantiating-a-widget-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn´t matter if your Widget is going to be Stateful or Stateless.

> A constant constructor is a constructor which initializes all its
> final fields, and it is often denoted with a const in front of the
> constructor

So, even if inside the class the values would change (...):

> The const keyword is used when the value of the variable is known at compile-time and never changes. In other words, the compiler knows in advance what value is to be stored in that variable.

(...) The final attributes inside the class remains the same (in this case just the `super.key` one).

Long story short:
By making a widget `const`, you can prevent it from being rebuilt when its parent is rebuilt, assuming its properties remain the same. This optimization improves performance by building the widget only once.

Comment: Ok so basically I just need to look at my constructor function and if everything in there is constant, then I can add `const` to wherever I call the class. But if it uses at least one `final` or `var` in the constructor function, then I can't use `const`. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually is the opposite, if you take a look at the linter rule on "https://dart.dev/diagnostics/const_constructor_with_non_final_field" it says that when there are non-final fields in the constructor, is a non-const one, for that in order to be a const constructor, it needs to have all the fields final.

Comment: Ahh ok. Thanks! If you have time, do you think you could help me on another issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003652/timer-variable-in-provider-fails-to-update-other-provider-variable

Answer (score 0):

It will prevent the Widget from being rebuild when its parent is rebuilt, as you already know that it will not change ever. Thus, only needing to build it once, you gain performance by making it a const.

**You can also disable const suggestion everywhere (but you shouldn't because it will help you to improve performance of your app)**

To avoid the prefer const with constant constructors warning add this rule prefer_const_constructors : false to the analysis_options.yaml file.

```
linter:
  rules:
    prefer_const_constructors : false
    # avoid_print: false  # Uncomment to disable the `avoid_print` rule
```