# Timer variable in provider fails to update other provider variable

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a button on my login form that starts a global timer and runs it on a 10 second frequency. The timer simply sets a global variable to `true`. While this value is `true`, the app navigates to a second screen.

On the second screen, there is a button I can press to make the variable `false`. When I press this, I see the terminal printing out that the current value of the variable is false but the app isn't going back to the first screen. It should go to screen #2 when the variable is `true` and go to screen #1 when the variable is `false`.

This unit test works when I don't use a timer - I've tested it with simple buttons on both screens to change the global variable and it works fine. It's just the timer that's messing things up.

**GlobalsProvider:**

```
void startLoginStream() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) => setToTrue());

    notifyListeners();
}

void setToTrue() {
    try {
      loggedIn = true;
      loggedInUser = 'user';

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {

    }
}

  void setToFalse() {
    try {
      loggedIn = false;
      loggedInUser = '';

      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {

    }
}
```

**screen #1:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Login'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                          //other asynchronous work...
                          value.startLoginStream();
                          context.go('/secondscreen');
                      },
                      child: const Text('TRUE TIMER'),
                    )
                   //...
```

**screen #2:**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
        builder: (context, value, child) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Forms'),
            ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: TextButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      value.setToFalse();
                    },
                    child: const Text('FALSE'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
    );
  }
```

**wrapper.dart (determines which screen to show):**

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  const Wrapper({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(builder: (context, value, child) {
      if (value.loggedIn == true) {
        return const Screen2();
      } else {
        return const Screen1(); 
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the line `context.go('/secondscreen');` after pressing the submit button. It uses the `go_router` package to switch to the next screen, but for some reason this was messing up the app's ability to flip between the two screens depending on the value of the global variable.